# Use of header ("locattion: xxx.php"); to move/retain control to tab on webpage

Tags: php, html

I have a tabbed webpage to perform database CRUD operations with this kind of tabs structure.

```
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">tab1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">tab3</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab4')">tab4</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
       <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab5')">Delete Record</button>
             DELETE QUERY;
             echo'Record deleted successfully';
             echo'Record not deleted successfully';
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab6')">View Record</button> //error
       </div> 
    <div id="tab5" class="tabcontent">
<!-- option 1 -->
    <div id="tab6" class="tabcontent">
    </div>

</div>
```

The problem is when I delete a record, after deletion the control goes to main page with all tabs. What I want is the control to return/remain to delete tab so the operation can continue.

My question is; is it possible to use  `header ("locattion: xxx.php");` tag to move/keep the delete tab open once the delete query has run and success/failure msg is displayed OR how to do that?

Here is the actual code the deletes the record & the control goes to to level tabs.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <h6> Fields </h6>
      <form action="" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div class="row"   style="background-color:lavender;">
     <div class="col mb-4">
      <label for="validationCustom01">Field ID</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id" placeholder="insert Field id" value="" required>
       </div>        
    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="submit111" type="submit">Delete Record</button>
      </form>

      <div id="search" class="col mb-4">

          <?php

            if(isset($_POST["submit111"])){
              $field_id = $_POST["field_id"];

            try {
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("Delete FROM fields where field_id = $field_id");

                 if ($stmt->execute()== TRUE) {
                 echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Record deleted Successfully');</script>";
                 } else { echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Record not deleted Successfully');</script>";}
                   }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                      // echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                         exit('<b>Catched exception at line '. $e->getLine() .' (code : '. $e->getCode() .') :</b> '. $e->getMessage());
                }
            }
                ?>
         </div>
       </div>
```

**EDIT**
**JS function to open tabs:**

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not introduce a `GET` parameter to switch the tabs? Why not perform the deletion using AJAX, which keeps you from such problems?

Comment: I tried using header while it raised error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent. How to use ?
For ajax, I have to covert all my code, so far it's without ajax. I am trying to find way, is it possible to do it without using ajax at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Question isnt complete, but it all depense on how you open the tabs.

If it is a anchor, just add the anchor to you header function like

```php
header("location: index.php#tab1");
```

or implement a get parameter that would set the active div(tab) on active.
or just fire a ajax request and let it be done in the background, so the tab stays active

Comment: thank you for the answer. I edited the code. There is a js function that is used to open the tab.